# Primality Macro in Common Lisp (SBCL)

Tags: macros, lisp, common-lisp, sbcl

Here is a macro which I wrote to test a number for primality:

```
(defmacro primep (num)
  `(not (or ,@(loop for p in *primes* collecting `(= (mod ,num ,p) 0)))))
```

`*primes*` is a dynamic variable which contains a list of the primes generated so far (the context is a 'next prime generator' function). Here are the results of a few eval-ed statements:

```
(let ((*primes* (list 2 3)))
  (primep 6))
-> T

(let ((*primes* (list 2 3)))
  (macroexpand-1 '(primep 6))
-> (NOT (OR (= (MOD 6 2) 0) (= (MOD 6 3) 0)))
-> T

(NOT (OR (= (MOD 6 2) 0) (= (MOD 6 3) 0)))
-> NIL
```

What is going on?

Comment: You should use a function for this. Macros are for generating code. The problem here is that the `LET` binding for `*PRIMES*` happens at run-time, not during macroexpansion.

Comment: @jkiiski How can I generate all those `(= (mod ...` statements using a function? I thought that was what macros are for (I've just started learning Common Lisp).

Comment: You don't need to generate them. Use a loop just like in any other language.

Comment: @jkiiski OK, thanks. I will try that. Can you add that (and maybe an example) as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use a function for this. Macros are for generating code. The problem here is that the `LET` binding for `*PRIMES*` happens at run-time, not during macroexpansion.

Your code as a function would look something like this.

```
(defparameter *primes* (list))

(defun primep (num)
  (not (loop for p in *primes* thereis (zerop (mod num p)))))

(let ((*primes* (list 2 3)))
  (primep 6))
;=> NIL

(let ((*primes* (list 2 3)))
  (primep 7))
;=> T
```

Comment: Is there any advantage to using `loop` with `thereis` over `dolist`?

Comment: No real advantage, but a `LOOP` is simpler to use. With `DOLIST` you have to write the exit from the loop yourself.